# SQL AOAG Primary replica on Secondary not connecting

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2022

Trying to set up an Always On Availability group on SQL Server 2022.

Group consists of 2 nodes.  No matter which direction I set it up, the server listed as Primary on the Secondary machine does not connect.  Both servers show as connected on the Primary machine.

Anyone have any idea whats going on here?

I have validated that both machines can talk to each other and that the End Points listed are correct.

Comment: You can start by looking at sys.dm_hadr_replica_states on the primary and the errorlogs of the primary and the secondary. Something should pop up. It'd be helpful to add your configuration to the question in terms of any scripts you used to configure the AG.

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows since you're using SQL Server.  Yes?  Without an error, it's hard to answer this.  But there's a high probability that this is your issue.  You likely don't allow port 1433 through or a service isn't running on the server(s).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417069/640205

Comment: If you are using Windows Server, the path to get at those configurations might be in a different spot, but Windows services and ports work the same on Windows Server as they do on Windows.

Comment: I would also check the Windows Event Log for errors